# What file can I change my static block's identifier?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm in my theme's local.xml file, and there only seems to be a couple, even though I have many. Where else could they be stored

Comment: Please be more clear on what you are asking. Did you write the static block in the admin panel?

Comment: @arqam Yes, I wrote it in the admin panel.